# Installing Ruby on rails Enterprise edition with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am wanna use RUBY ON RAILS ENTERPRISE EDITION, but would like to install it using RVM so that I can switch back to other versions. I googled but did not get the relevant answers regarding this. Google results showed me that, I can install dependently but not with RVM.

Kindly suggest or let me know if is there any way, I can install ROR enterprise with RVM

Comment: May be do you mean Ruby Enterprise Edition? Rails is a set of gems and not depends on the rvm

Comment: First [install RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) then `rvm install ree` and finally `gem install rails`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean ruby enterprise edition?

If yes, `rvm install ree` should work.